# Evaluating expression inside GSP tags

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I am trying to evaluate an expression in a GSP tag. Crudely put,

```
<g:form ${true ? 'name=\"hello\"' : ''}>
```

But the error I'm getting is:

```
Class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
Message: Attribute value must be quoted (${true ? 'name=\"hello\"' : ''}).
```

In one of the other views, the following expression (which is similar to the above one) works fine.

```
<li ${controllerName == null ? ' class=active' : ''}>
```

But it does not work with the form tag. I am using Grails 2.3.5. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I am having similar problems with this expression too.

```
<g:form url="[${multiple ? '' : 'resource:xyzInstance, '}action:'update']" method="PUT" >
```

Here, `multiple` is a boolean value. It works fine with an `<g:if>` tag.

```
<g:if test="${multiple}">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Groovy double quotes must not be escaped inside single quote strings.
The opposite also applies: single quotes must not be escaped inside double quote strings (known as GStrings, by the way)

Try

```
<g:form ${true ? 'name="hello"' : ''}>
```

or

```
<g:form ${true ? "name=\"hello\"" : ''}>
```

Both will work.

For the second part of the updated question I would recommend to build the map separately as it is not only going to work but your code is going to be easier to read and maintain. Something like:

```
<%
def urlMap = [action: 'update']
if(multiple)
urlMap.put 'resource', 'xyzInstance'
%>
<g:form url="${urlMap}" method="PUT">
```

Be careful also with the types you use as values on some attributes, this has caused me some troubles sometimes:

- 'a String'
- "a GString with a ${dynamicValue}"
- "[a GString that looks like a list]"
- "${[a, list]}"
- "${[a: map]}"
- "false" <- This will always be evaluated to true, as it's a non-empty non-null GString
- "${false}" <- Solution to the problem of the line above

I hope all this solve your problems. For simplicity's sake I'd always recommend to keep value expressions as simple as possible, and if they need complex logic put it in a block immediately before the tag it's gonna benefit from it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is not the real expression

```
<g:form ${true ? 'name=\"hello\"' : ''}>
```

Because there's no point is using an expression for this, as it's equivalent to:

```
<g:form name="hello">
```

I guess what you need is something like

```
<g:form name="${someVariable ? 'hello' : ''}">
```

If this doesn't help, could you update your question to show the real expression?

Comment: It must be just an example. There are some situations where it makes sense to generate the attribute name as well, like adding checked attribute to a check box for instance, or adding data attributes depending on dynamic circumstances

Comment: I wrote `${true}` just as an example. I am well aware that I don't have to evaluate it to have a `name` attribute. Thanks!